# Trailing Zeros - How many trailing zeros are there in 100! (factorial of 100)?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

Here's the question:
How many trailing zeros are there in 100! (factorial of 100)?

Here's the solution:
This is an easy problem. We know that each pair of 2 and 5 will give a trailing zero. If we perform prime number decomposition on all the numbers in 100!, it is obvious that the frequency of 2 will far outnumber of the frequency of 5. So the frequency of 5 determines the number of trailing zeros. Among numbers 1,2,....,99, and 100, 20 numbers are divisible by 5 (5, 10, ...., 100). Among these 20 numbers, 4 are divisible by 5^2 (25, 50, 75, 100). So the total frequency of 5 is 24 and there are 24 trailing zeros.

What I don't understand is... what is trailing zero? And how did the author use 2 and 5? (2 and 5 seem pretty random to me).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing is clear.  $2 \times 5 = 10$ and there is no other way to get 10 out of 2 prime numbers.

"trailing zeros" are the zeros at the end of the number.
For example: 3200 has 2 trailing zeros. The units and the tenths position.

One other thing is clear.
Multiplying a number by 10 adds a trailing zero to that number.

So in order to find the number of zeros at the tail of a number, you need to split that number into prime factors and see how many pairs (2, 5) you can form.

For example:

300 has 2 trailing zeros.  Why?
because $300 = 3 \times 2 ^ 2 \times 5^2$.
So you get 2 pairs of (5, 2).

An other example:

$4000 = 2^5 \times 5 ^3 = 2 ^2 \times (2 \times 5) ^ 3$
Hence, 3 trailing zeros.

EDIT:

For your specific question. 100!.

$100! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times .... \times 100$.

Which is equivalent to splitting every number into prime factors like this:

$100! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 2^2 \times 5 \times (3\times 2) .... \times (2 \times 5)^2$

You need to count how many 10's you can make out of these prime numbers.
As explained above, the only way to get a 10 is $2 \times 5$.
So you need to count how many 2's and how many 5s are among the prime factors above.

The 5s can appear only in numbers that are divisible by 5.

```
5, 10, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50 , 55, 60 , 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100
```

and the number of 5s in the numbers above are

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
```

Because for example

$15 = 3 \times 5$ so one single 5.
$50 = 2 \times 5 ^2$ so 2 fives.

Add them all up and you get 24 occurrences of 5.

Now you need to see if there are at least 24 occurrences of 2.
And they are because form 1 to 100 you have 50 even numbers (they all contain at least one 2).

This means that 100! can be written as

$2 ^ {50} \times 5 ^ {24} \times$ (some other factors that are never going to multiply to get to a multiple of 10 so we can ignore them).

We can split the line above (ignoring the factors that cannot multiply to reach a multiple of 10) to

$2 ^ {24} \times 2 ^{26} \times 5^{24} = (2 \times 5) ^{24} \times 2 ^{26}$

We can ignore again $2^{26}$ because that never ends with zeros (it ends with a 4 if I'm not mistaken)

Now you can see that 100! is basically a very large number that does not end with a 0 multiplied by $10 ^ {24}$. So you get 24 trailing zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I definitely understand it better. There are two questions:
1. How can this concept be applied to a factorial?
2. Why does the statement 'the frequency of 2 will far outnumber the frequency of 5' matter?

Comment: See my edit. I added a few explanations for your specific case.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing zeroes are as the name points zeroes in the end of the number. So 10 has 1 trailing zero. And because this is a question regarding base10 numbers, this is how you can represent any number with trailing zero -  number0 = number x 10.
And because 10 is actually 2 x 5 you need 2s and 5s. One 2 is enough to 'turn' all fives into zeroes. And you already have posted the number of 5s.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I definitely understand it better. There are two questions: 1. How can this concept be applied to a factorial? 2. Why does the statement 'the frequency of 2 will far outnumber the frequency of 5' matter?